# How to obtain a a Cookie's expiration date?

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

I have a `Fiddler.Session` object named `oS`

I can obtain it's cookies like this:

```
oS.oRequest["Cookie"];
```

However, is there a way to obtain expiration date of each cookie?

Comment: @  I don't know about FiddlerCore, but a [Cookie class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie(v=vs.110).aspx) has properties that let you evaluate the content af a cookie See `.Expires`. If that `oS.oRequest["Cookie"]` is translated to a cookie object or passed to a CookieContainer, that is easily done. Of course you can parse it manually. It's content might be Base64Encoded.

Comment: one example of oS.oRequest["Cookie"] is !!! "na_id=2017083102065780667985115773; ssc=myvidster%3B3; na_tc=Y; mus=0; uid=599f9375fdb0a7b6; loc=MDAwMDBOQUNBUUMyMjgxMTAyMjAwMDAwMDAwVg==; uvc=223%7C47%2C280%7C48%2C325%7C49%2C409%7C50%2C141%7C51"
!!! where cookies are separated by ;. I'm no cookie expert. The is a lot of cookie in that, but doesn't seem to have an expiratino date?

Comment: Not all cookies have an "Expire" value set. Session Cookies expire at the and of the session and must be reloaded every time you connect to the server. They may have an expiration set before a session begins, then only a value is applied. What I see here is one Cookie with some parameters. **loc** is Base64Encoded and its value is `00000NACAQC2281102200000000V`, **uvc** is URLEncoded, its value is `223|47,280|48,325|49,409|50,141|51`.

Comment: thanks a lot!! I need to automate this. So to decode if, how do I know how it is encoded? And then how do I interprete the value??

Comment: I will eventually delete this question today and ask a new one more clear with info you've given

Comment: I posted this (and current one will be deleted) since now I understand more the problem, the current question appears to be wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47931454/how-to-interpret-cookies